# Standard Visitor visa validity

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, visa-expiration

I have a tourist visa to UK from July 26, 2015 to January 26, 2016.

How do they count the months I'm going to stay in UK - from the time I arrived in UK or I will be allowed only the months stated in my passport, that is July 26 to January 26, 2016?

Comment: The simple answer is that you must leave the UK no later than the end date on your visa, i.e. no later than Jan.26 2016.  I remember seeing a page on the UKBA website with a visa specimen image and description of what each field means, but I'm having difficulties finding it now.

Comment: @AleksG, that's good for an answer. There's no need for an image of an entry clearance.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that you must leave the UK no later than the end date on your visa, i.e. no later than Jan.26 2016.

When you received your visa, it should have arrived with a one-page pamphlet titled "How to read your visa".  That pamphlet explains what each of the fields mean, including the validity date for the visa.